# C: How to implement the strcat and strcpy functions?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to implement these functions for a school assignment. I know what the logic of my program is, but it's behaving a little strangely. I would appreciate some help here

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *StrCat (char *destination, const char* source) {
    destination = malloc(sizeof(source) + sizeof(destination));
    char *temp = destination;
    while (*temp != '\0') {
        printf("temp: %c - ", *temp);
        temp++;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; source[i] != 0; i++) {
        *temp = source[i];
    }
    temp[i++] = 0;
    return destination;
}

char *StrCpy(char *destination, const char* source) {
    destination = malloc(sizeof(source) * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }
    destination[i++] = '\0';
    return destination;
}

int main ()
{
   char *src;
   char *dest;

   src = StrCpy(src,  "A source sentence");
   dest = StrCpy(dest, "This is the destination sentence");

   printf("%s\n%s\n", src, dest);

   StrCat(dest, src);

   printf("Final destination string : |%s|", dest);

   return(0);
}
```

This is the output

```
A source sen
This is the destination sentence
temp: i - temp: n - temp: a - temp: t - temp: i - temp: o - temp: n - temp:   - temp: s - temp: e - temp: n - temp: t - temp: Q - temp: e - temp: s - temp: t - Final destination string : |This is the |
```

Also, when I comment out the

```
dest = StrCpy(dest, "This is the destination sentence");
```

line, I get this output

```
A source sentence
(null)
temp: e - Final destination string : |(null)|
```

My question is: Why is it that src prints correctly when I don't call StrCpy on dest? Also, in the first output, why is it that temp starts out at the letter i, when it's supposed to be pointing to the first element of destination?

Thank You

Comment: You don't need `malloc`. The working buffer is already allocated and sent as first parameter.

Comment: @i486: In both functions?

Comment: (in main) `char *dest;`is uninitialized.

Comment: Yes. Both (standard) functions assume that first parameter is pointer to buffer.

Comment: @i486: When I remove the malloc lines, I get a runtime error

Comment: Have to define `char *src` as `char src[256]` (or other size). Same for `dest`.

Comment: `sizeof(source)` etc. does not what you think…

Comment: Ok, the strange behavior is gone. May I know why it was happening in the first place. What does me not initializing src and dest property move the temp pointer to another position? Also, why doesn't src print properly?

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted me, may I know why? I think I did everything I was supposed to, when asking questions? I provided my code, clearly showed what the problem was. I think it was a reasonable question. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with your use of `sizeof()`.

In the following situation, `sizeof()` will return the size of a *pointer* on your system (probably 4 / 8 bytes), not the size of a `char`, or the length of the string (which is how you appear to be using it).

```c
char *myString;
printf("sizeof(myString): %d\n", sizeof(myString));
```

What you are actually looking for is the size of the type that the pointer is pointing to... to do this, you need to 'dereference' the pointer once. This will give you the size of a single `char`.

```c
char *myString;
printf("sizeof(myString): %d\n", sizeof(*myString));
```

To get the length of a string, you need to use `strlen()`:

```c
char myString[] = "Testing 123...";
printf("string length: %d\n", strlen(myString));
```

---

Next up, you need to check your understanding of `strcpy()`...
The standard [`strcpy(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) will expect both `source` and `destination` to be existing buffers. It will also expect that destination has enough storage to hold the entirety of source, plus a nul terminator (`'\0'`).
If this is not true, then your application may (hopefully will) crash with a Segmentation Fault, or overwrite other variables.
This is one of the reasons that the use of `strcpy()` is often frowned upon in industry - prefer to use `strncpy()`.

> The `strncpy()` function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.
>   Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

---

I would prefer to see you implementing functions with the following prototypes, if your tutor complains, then an extension of your assignment is to understand why having the `n` parameter is important, and explain it to them.

```c
/* append the 'source' to the 'destination', allowing the total length of 'destination' to
 * be no longer than 'n' bytes, including the terminating nul */
char *StrnCat (char *destination, const char* source, size_t n);

/* copy the 'source' to the 'destination', allowing the total length of 'destination' to
 * be no longer than 'n' bytes, including the terminating nul */
char *StrnCpy(char *destination, const char* source, size_t n);
```

If you allocate the storage for your strings in the `main()` function, then you don't need to worry about `malloc()` at all.

This is a learning opportunity, so I'm not going to implement them for you.

Comment: While `strcpy()` has one set of problems associated with it, `strncpy()` has a different, much bigger set of problems associated with it.  In particular, if you have `char buffer[100000]; strncpy(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "abc");`, how many bytes are modified in `buffer`?  If you didn't say 100,000, you fell into the trap.  The `strncat()` function is even worse: `char buffer[10000] = ""; memset(buffer, 'X', 5000); char aux[10000] = ""; memset(aux, 'Y', sizeof(aux)-1); strncat(buffer, what_goes_here, aux);` — what goes where I wrote `what_goes_here`?  The answer is not `sizeof(buffer)`!

Comment: Your `source` and `n` parameters are swapped. What does it matter *how many* bytes are modified? So long as no memory access is made past the end of the buffer, things are fine - of course to test the success you need to call `strnlen()`, not `strlen()` afterwards. As for the `n` parameter for `strncat()`, yes it is indeed `sizeof(buffer)` (we are preventing and overrun of `buffer` after all), and if you genuinely are trying to concat two strings that total more than your dest buffer, then your code is broken (confirm failure with `strnlen()`).

Comment: Ir can be quicker and more clear to do string handling yourself, where you can intrinsically know if something succeeded, without having to check.

Comment: My bad on the argument order for `strncpy()` and `strncat()`.  It partly shows how often I use them, though.

Comment: The specification of `strncat()` from the standard is: _The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and
characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of
the string pointed to by `s1`._  If you specified `sizeof(buffer)` as the space to `strncat()`, you would incur buffer overflow (undefined behaviour).  The _only_ time it is safe to use `strncat(buffer, other_string, sizeof(buffer))` is when you know `buffer[0] == '\0'`. This is the reason I regard `strncat()` as very unsafe — most people do not know how it behaves.

Comment: Good point (I'd forgotten that too, and consider the implementation/spec broken). Though `if ((strlen(buffer) + strlen(other_string) + 1) < sizeof(buffer)) ...` would work.

Comment: Yes, but to be safe, you have to know how much data is already stored in the target string, and if you know that, you don't need to use `strncat()` to skip over the initial segment; you can simply pass a pointer to the null byte and specify the correct size. (If you insist on using the return value from `strncat()` in a function call (`printf("%s\n", strncat(…))` for example), then it matters which pointer you pass to it because that pointer is returned.  I don't recall ever using that with any of the `str*()` functions — though I probably did a few times, few being the operative term.)